# Setting Sentence Capitalization on EditText Programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, capitalization

Without using XML, how do I set EditText to capitalize sentences and still have predictive text working? I tried `EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)` and that works but it disables predictive text. How do I get predictive text and sentence capitalization both on, without using XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, found it! `EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);`